# Why doesn't django accept my custom filter with any name except 'cut'?

Tags: django

Guys I see wired issue with django. I am trying to create my own custom filter and **it only works if I name it "cut"** but it will never work with any other names:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='cut')
def removeText(value, arg):
    return value.replace(arg,'')
```

and this is how I call it in the template

```
<h1>{{text|cut:"hello"}}</h1>
```

**This is the error message if I rename it @register.filter(name='cut1')**

[image]

Comment: maybe need define it as template tag and import `file.py` in html. Like doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thank you @NgocPham. This is what I need to do. By the way, when I kept changing the name many times after this step, I got error again like it is not registered filter. So it is important to restart the server.

Comment: i will add it as answer :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define it as template tag and import `file.py` in html. 
Doc for template tag
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Exactly this is the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to load the template tag filter in the template, due to which it is using the Django's in-built [cut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) filter.

Do refrain from naming your template tags the same as the in-built tag names.

**Solution**:

```
{% load cut1 %}
```

**EDIT**: You should name the file containing the filter function as `cut1.py` to load `cut1` in the template.

Comment: I tried this tag but I got error: **'cut1' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
my_extras
static
staticfiles
tz**

Comment: You should load the filename and not the function name. Did you miss that?@jess

Comment: I applied @NgocPham solution and it is working. I should load my filters file inside the template then I can call the filter.